# Infinite loop "Are you sure you want to buy this item?" in the App Store

Tags: itunes, applications, ipod-touch

I have the latest Apple iPod touch. I just received a iTunes gift card and started downloading free apps.
When I try to download apps that are $0.99 or higher, it asks me for my billing information. After I hit clicked 'done', it asks me if I still want to buy the item. I say yes and it starts asking me for my billing info again and then if I'm sure again and again...
Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried going to http://appleid.apple.com and confirming your billing information there (going to billing, clicking submit) and then trying again ;-)